# simple CSS animation, should I be doing this in canvas or SVG?

Tags: html, css, canvas, svg

the first two keys are operational (leftmost key, and the black key right next to it).  here it is hosted so you can see

```
http://23.23.184.26/miller/keyboardanimation/main.html
```

I have to redraw the WHOLE keyboard because the 3d nature of each key does not leave a square profile that I can replace with a square image.  I don't see support anywhere for trapezoidal elements...

Should I be doing this in SVG or canvas or something?  I feel like the way I'm doing this is really dumb.

And, I'm getting a wierd white flash between transitions sometimes (on IE9 only tho I think)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        a{
            color:white;
        }
        #main{
            background:white url('0.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
            position:relative;
            z-index:0;
            width:506px;
            height:319px;
        }

        #key1{
            position:absolute;
            width:50px;
            height:75px;
            top:175px;
            left:55px; 
        }
        #key2{
            position:absolute;
            width:50px;
            height:75px;
            top:100px;
            left:85px;
        }
        /*uncomment this to show button zones*/
        /*#key1:hover, #key2:hover{
            border:1px solid red;
        }*/
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="key1" onMouseDown="document.getElementById('main').style.background = 'url(1.gif)'" onMouseUp="document.getElementById('main').style.background = 'url(0.gif)'"></div>
        <div id="key2" onMouseDown="document.getElementById('main').style.background = 'url(2.gif)'" onMouseUp="document.getElementById('main').style.background = 'url(0.gif)'"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You might be interested in my [animation on a curve](http://phrogz.net/svg/animation_on_a_curve.html) demo, which uses SVG internally to animate any properties in 2D space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using CSS animation :-/, you are making simple background transition using Javascript.

That said there is also another small detail, if you use canvas to draw and animate the piano, you will need to "re-draw" the piano that doesn't change and every part of the piano that changes.

I would suggest that you do this in SVG and animate that, as you will have less parts to animate :-).

Greetings!
Gonzalo G.

Comment: Also, the blinking is caused by the time that takes to load the images, since the images are only loaded when used (or by using a image preloading technique)

Comment: meh, I'm just learning.  Was hoping to avoid svg...but I guess there is a library (raphael) for it?

Comment: I haven't done any complex animations (nothing more fancy that a circle moving or so), so I can't help you there :-S. But as far as I know, now is very easy to do :-).

Perhaps this site could help you a little it has plenty of examples http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/